# How can i animate widget to it's max Height without to change value

Tags: flutter, dart, animation

so for example using `AnimatedContainer` we can animate the `Height` or `width` once we change it's values .

but How could we do the same animation being happen by its first construction or first initialization of the widget

on other word: the following code i used `AnimatedContainer` only to show the wanted animation

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late bool boolValue =  false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: AnimatedContainer(
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          color: Colors.blue,
          height: !boolValue? 200:0,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: const [
                Text('Hello world , Hello Dart',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 15),),
                Text('Hello world , Hello Dart',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 15),),
                Text('Hello world , Hello Dart',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 15),),
                Text('Hello world , Hello Dart',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 15),),
                Text('Hello world , Hello Dart',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 15),),
              ],
            ),
          ),
       )
      ),
        floatingActionButton:  FloatingActionButton(
            backgroundColor:  const Color(0xFFE57373),
            onPressed: (){
              setState(() {boolValue = !boolValue;});
            },
            child:  const Icon(Icons.check)
        )
    );
  }
}
```

so i need the same animation but by as mush as widget Building or rebuilding  it's self (including the first initialization )

Note: i don't want use AnimatedContainer or any process of changing the value , since i need widget doing this job it's self

like lets say the widget start from 0 height , 0 width then animate to expanding to it's max height and width content in every time the widget  rebuilding it's self (including the first initialization )

edit .. in the following gif i only mean the animation part it's self . from completely hidden point to completely visible point and the animation happen to whole widget without affection to it's content like resize .

i need the animation auto happen every time the widget rebuilding it's self (including the first initialization )

[image]

is there widget or any way . thanks

Comment: Can you include a gif of your desire output?

Comment: thank you so mush , i uploaded gif with some hints